# iTextPDF Library - Can't find the class "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter"

Tags: itext, itextpdf

Can't find the class "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter" in latest version of itextpad v5.4.0. I have even tried downloading the extra jars but to no avail.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As said by Bruno, PDF/A Libraries are in a different jar file: **itext-pdfa**.

Here the Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-pdfa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: workos only with dependency `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.13</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 4):

I'm the original developer of iText; I made the 5.4.0 release, but I've never heard of itextpad. If you [download the release from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/iText5.4.0/), you'll find PdfAWriter in the extra jar named itext-pdfa-5.4.0.jar.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. I meant itextpdf only. I downloaded the jar itextpdf from Maven central repository. Do you have the itext-pdfa-5.4.0 in maven?

Comment: No, I only published the core iText on Maven. I'm not very familiar with Maven (I always run into trouble when I use it). A long time ago, I hired somebody to write a script that takes care of making a bundle for the core Java, but that script predates the pdfa package.